# How I can Normalize the below given PDF?

Tags: probability-or-statistics, distributions, mathematica-online

I have tried  to Normalize the below Code PDF with a such Constant K But I didn't succeed , I have used this instruction: `mv\[ScriptCapitalD]=ProbabilityDistribution[f[x,\[Mu]], {x, 0, \[Infinity]},Method->"Normalize"]` , But no result .

MY cODE for PDF Here:(The integrand over sigma is about 0.99..), Any help ?

```
 f[z_?NumericQ, \[Mu]_?NumericQ] := 
      NIntegrate[
   K* Sqrt[Sqrt [ 2]*Pi]/2*Exp[-Sqrt[Sqrt[2]*Pi](z+\[Sigma])^2/\[Mu]*Sqrt[Pi*\[Sigma]]
    * Erf[\[Mu](z-\[Sigma])^2/(Sqrt[Pi*\[Sigma]])]], {\[Sigma],1, \[Infinity]}]
    pdfF[\[Mu]_?NumericQ] := PDF[ProbabilityDistribution[f[x,\[Mu] ], {x, 0, \[Infinity]}]]
    With[{n = 5},
      Show[
          Plot[
            Labeled[pdfF[#1][z], Row[{"\[Mu] = ", Rationalize[#1]}], Above], {z, 0, 5},
            PlotRange -> All,
            PlotStyle -> #2] &
        @@@
          Rest[{#, Hue[#]} & /@ Subdivide[0., 1., n]],
      ImageSize -> Large]]
    With[{n = 5}, NIntegrate[pdfF[#][z], {z, 0, 5}] & /@ (Range[n]/n)]

    Plot[Evaluate[f[z_?NumericQ, \[Mu]_?NumericQ] ], {x, 0, 10},{\[Mu],0,1}, AxesOrigin \[RightArrow] {0, 0},
    Epilog \[RightArrow] {Dashed, Line[{{0, f[z_?NumericQ, \[Mu]_?NumericQ]}, {10, f[z_?NumericQ, \[Mu]_?NumericQ]}}]}, PlotRange \[RightArrow] {{0, 10}, {0, 1}}]
```

This is the plot that i have got for n=5 [image]

Comment: Please define `K` and trim the unnecessary code.  Why does `z` only go from 0 to 5?  Just executing `Plot[f[x, 4], {x, 0, 20}]` (with `K=1`) shows some oddities.

Comment: @JimB ,This is what I have used for normalization but it doesn't work:mv\[ScriptCapitalD] = 
 ProbabilityDistribution[  k*Sqrt[10Sqrt [ 2]*Pi]/(2*Pi)*Exp[-Pi*Sqrt[2*\[Sigma]](z+\[Sigma])^2
* Erf[\[Mu](z-\[Sigma])^2/Sqrt[Sqrt[2]*Pi*\[Sigma]] ]/\[Mu],{\[Sigma], 1,Infinity}], {z, 0,5},{\[Mu], 0,1} ,{k,1,Infinity},
  Method -> "Normalize"]

Comment: I think the issue is with the limits used for `NIntegrate`.  Using 1 through $\infty$ doesn't allow `Nintegrate` to work well.  I'll add an example as an extended comment.

Comment: This is my PDF formula :$$\int_1^{\infty } \frac{\sqrt{10 \sqrt{2} \pi } \exp \left(-\frac{\pi  \sqrt{2 \sigma
   } (z+\sigma )^2 \text{erf}\left(\frac{\mu  (z-\sigma )^2}{\sqrt{\sqrt{2} \pi 
   \sigma }}\right)}{\mu }\right)}{0.997266 \times2 \pi } \, d\sigma$$

Answer (score 1):

This is an extended comment.

I think the issue is that using `{σ, 1, ∞}` for the limits of integration doesn't allow `NIntegrate` to work well.  (Yes, those are what the limits should be.)  Here's an example.

```
integrand[z_, μ_, σ_] := Sqrt[Sqrt[2]*Pi]/2*
  Exp[-Sqrt[Sqrt[2]*Pi] (z + σ)^2/μ*Sqrt[Pi*σ]*Erf[μ (z - σ)^2/(Sqrt[Pi*σ])]]

Plot[integrand[4.75, 4, σ], {σ, 1, 6}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image: Integrand over sigma]

Now if we integrate over two different limits of integration:

```
NIntegrate[integrand[4.75, 4, σ], {σ, 1, ∞}]
(* 1.5504*10^-15 )*

NIntegrate[integrand[4.75, 4, σ], {σ, 4.5, 5.1}]
(* 0.127522 *)
```

The latter result makes more sense.  So when determining `K` one will need to adjust the limits of integration for different values of `z` and `μ`.  However, I don't have an idea as to automate that process with reasonable limits of integration.

Comment: Do you meant that can't be a PDF over the range of sigma ? , I have did the same Idea , the integral dosn't work as well for example in the Range (10,25)

Comment: No.  I'm just saying that one needs to be careful with assigning limits of integration with this function.  Just using `{\[sigma],1,Infinity}` many times misses where the integrand is most positive and one ends up with an erroneous value of near zero.  It might very well be that the integral over $z$ (not $\sigma$) is infinite.  But you need to fix the issue with `NIntegrate` first.

Comment: The value of Mu are in (0,1)